# trigger a method from other class when clicking a button on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I just made an "app" that just prints something up in the command line (outpot)
heres an example -

http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/2853/3cc0a810d7564e39b05bade.png

Code:

Card.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Card : NSObject {
    int CardValue;
    int CardType;
}
@property int CardValue,CardType;
@end
```

Card.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Card : NSObject {
    int CardValue;
    int CardType;
}
@property int CardValue,CardType;
@end
```

Deck.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Card.h"
@interface Deck : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *Deck1, *Deck2, *Deck3, *Deck4, *Deck5;
}
@property NSMutableArray *Deck1, *Deck2, *Deck3, *Deck4, *Deck5;
-(void)createDeck;
-(void)createFullDeck : (Deck *) TheDeck;
-(void)insertToDeck : (Card *) TheCard;
@end
```

Deck.m:

```
#import "Deck.h"
#include <stdlib.h> 
@implementation Deck
@synthesize Deck1, Deck2, Deck3, Deck4, Deck5;
-(void)createDeck{
Deck1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:13];
Deck2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:13];
Deck3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:13];
Deck4 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:13];
Deck5 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:13];
}
-(void)createFullDeck : (Deck *) TheDeck{
    Card *Card1 = [[Card alloc]init];
    [TheDeck createDeck];
    for (int i=1;i<=4;i++){
        for (int j=1;j<=13;j++){
            Card1.CardValue=j;
            Card1.CardType=i;
            [TheDeck insertToDeck:Card1];
        }
    }
}
-(void)insertToDeck : (Card *) TheCard{
if (TheCard.CardType==1)
    [Deck1 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:TheCard.CardValue]];
if (TheCard.CardType==2)
    [Deck2 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:TheCard.CardValue]];
if (TheCard.CardType==3)
    [Deck3 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:TheCard.CardValue]];
if (TheCard.CardType==4)
    [Deck4 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:TheCard.CardValue]];
}
-(id)DrawCard{
    Card *MethodCard = [[Card alloc]init];
    int randomType = arc4random() % 4;
    if (randomType==0){
        int DeckCount = [Deck1 count];
        int randomValue = arc4random() % DeckCount;
        MethodCard.CardValue = [[Deck1 objectAtIndex:randomValue]integerValue];
        [Deck1 removeObjectAtIndex:randomValue];
    }
    if (randomType==1){
        int DeckCount = [Deck2 count];
        int randomValue = arc4random() % DeckCount;
        MethodCard.CardValue =[[Deck2 objectAtIndex:randomValue]integerValue];
        [Deck2 removeObjectAtIndex:randomValue];
    }
    if (randomType==2){
        int DeckCount = [Deck3 count];
        int randomValue = arc4random() % DeckCount;
        MethodCard.CardValue =[[Deck3 objectAtIndex:randomValue]integerValue];
        [Deck3 removeObjectAtIndex:randomValue];
    }
    if (randomType==3){
        int DeckCount = [Deck4 count];
        int randomValue = arc4random() % DeckCount;
        MethodCard.CardValue =[[Deck4 objectAtIndex:randomValue]integerValue];
        [Deck4 removeObjectAtIndex:randomValue];
    }
    MethodCard.CardType = randomType+1;
    return MethodCard;
}
@end
```

Game.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Deck.h"
@interface Game : NSObject

-(void)StartNewGame : (Deck *) TheDeck : (Game *) TheGame;
-(BOOL)GetDecision : (int) TheNumber;
-(void)CheckHiOrLo : (int) FirstNumber : (Deck *) TheDeck : (Game *) TheGame;
@end
```

Game.m:

```
#import "Game.h"
@implementation Game
-(void)StartNewGame : TheDeck : (Game *) TheGame{
    NSLog(@"Welcome to the game High-Low!");
    [TheDeck createDeck];
    [TheDeck createFullDeck:TheDeck];
    Card *TheCard = [[Card alloc]init];
    TheCard = [TheDeck DrawCard];
    [TheGame CheckHiOrLo: TheCard.CardValue : TheDeck : TheGame];
    }
-(BOOL)GetDecision : (int) TheNumber{
    int userNum=0;
    NSLog(@"The Card is %i\nif you think the next Card is going to be higher - type 1.\nif you think the next Card is going to be lower - type 0.", TheNumber);
    scanf("%i", &userNum);
    if(userNum==1)
        return YES;
    if(userNum==0)
        return NO;
    NSLog(@"error in GetDecision in Game.m");
    return NO;
}
-(void)CheckHiOrLo : (int) FirstNumber : (Deck *) TheDeck : (Game *) TheGame{
    Card *TheCard = [[Card alloc]init];
    TheCard = [TheDeck DrawCard];
    BOOL Decision = [TheGame GetDecision:FirstNumber];
    if(FirstNumber>TheCard.CardValue){
        if(Decision==YES){
            NSLog(@"%i", TheCard.CardValue);
            NSLog(@"GameOver");
        }
        if(Decision==NO){
            NSLog(@"%i \nCorrect, Next Card", TheCard.CardValue);
            [TheGame CheckHiOrLo: TheCard.CardValue : TheDeck : TheGame];
        }
    }
    if(FirstNumber<=TheCard.CardValue){
        if(Decision==YES){
            NSLog(@"%i \nCorrect, Next Card", TheCard.CardValue);
            [TheGame CheckHiOrLo: TheCard.CardValue : TheDeck : TheGame];
        }
        if(Decision==NO){
            NSLog(@"%i", TheCard.CardValue);
            NSLog(@"GameOver");
        }
    }
}
@end
```

So now i try to make a iPhone app for that, so i made a new iphone project, moved the Card,Deck and Game Classes to the iPhone project and made a High button, a Low button, and a start button to buid a new deck.

now how do i do that when i click the Start Button, it will trigger the method createDeck and CreateFullDeck that are in Deck Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would make `Deck` a declared object in your header file of, lets say your `UIViewController`, make sure you `#import Deck.h`.

```
#import "Deck.h"

@interface MainViewController: UIViewController

      Deck *deck;
@end
```

Now, you can initialize your `deck` in `-viewDidLoad` method of MainViewController

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

     deck = [[Deck alloc] init];
 }
```

On your button action, you will create the full deck. Assuming this is an `IBAction` connected to a `UIButton` in Interface Builder;

```
 -(IBAction)onCreateClicked:(id)sender {

      [deck createDeck:deck];
      // You now created your deck of cards.
   }
```

Hope this helps !

**EDIT**: After investigating your code further, There are numerous things wrong with your code, but above example will do what you're asking to do.

Comment: Build Failed.  It gives me this details:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Deck", referenced from:
     obj-class-ref in ViewController.o
id: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Make sure `Deck` class's are properly imported and in your project, as well as in `Compile Sources` build phase for the target.

Comment: Ok got it working by making a fresh new project.
Thank you very much!